# order() function in R

Tags: r

I used order() function to do the following

```
x<-c(12,5,13,8)
order(x)
```

It gives the following result, indicating it is in descending order

```
[1] 2 4 1 3
```

However, when I typed the following

```
x<-c(12,11,13,14)
order(x)
```

It gives a result that is in ascending order

```
[1] 2 1 3 4
```

I am not quite sure if I missed anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in both the cases it seems ascending order . check it

Comment: The answer seems correct! In both the cases it is in ascending order.

Answer (score 3):

Order returns the row numbers in ascending order of `x` ( by default). So your output is as expected.

In case you were expecting the vector `x` to be ordered :

```
> x<-c(12,5,13,8)

# returns row numbers
> order(x)
[1] 2 4 1 3

# returns the ordered vector#############
> x[order(x)]
[1]  5  8 12 13
```

To order in descending order , use :

```
 > x[order(x, decreasing = TRUE)]
[1] 13 12  8  5
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just mistaken in the way you were reading the function.
The numbers that are being returned are the position in your vector.

Your first example:

> x <- c(12,5,13,8)
>
> order(x)

[1] 2 4 1 3

This is telling you that, in an ascending order, the first number is in the second position = 5, the second number is in the fourth position = 8, and so on.